# How can I get the same look as the standard with an owner draw menu?

Tags: winapi, menu, ownerdrawn

I consider using an owner draw menu in a Windows application that should have the same look as the standard menu. (Reason: the standard menu doesn't work well in some mixed DPI situations.)

Currently I have a problem providing the correct width during *WM_MEASUREITEM*.

This is a screenshot of the Edit menu of notepad where each item has a shortcut.

[image: standard menu]

We can see that there is a constant gap between the item texts and shortcut texts as if they were columns. It seems as if the widths of the item texts and the widths of the shortcut texts are retrieved separately, as the longest item text "Time/Date" reserves a shortcut width suitable for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> while it only needs one for <kbd>F5</kbd>.

I could not find any API functionality where I can give the width of the item text and the shortcut text separately, nor did I find any metric specifying the size of the gap.

So my question is: Is it possible to achieve the desired behavior within the usual *WM_MEASUREITEM* message and if yes, how? If not, is there any other means to get this right or is it just not possible at all?

Comment: Windows is full of bugs in mixed-DPI situations, sadly.

Comment: FWIW, menu labels use a tab character to separate the left-hand label from the right-hand hotkey string. So in your implementation, you would need to iterate through all the items in the menu, retrieve the label text, split it at the tab, calculate the widths of both parts of the label, remember the maximum, and then use that plus some padding to specify the width of the menu item.

Comment: @JonathanPotter, although the splitting is not necessary to get both parts, as I already haven them separate, the problem is to find the proper event to do that iteration. WM_MESUREITEM is called for each menu item, while the proposed iteration has to be done before or latest with the last WM_MEASUREITEM. In the both cases do I need a trigger to either start the iteration or reset the current values. Do you know which message could be used for that? Perhaps something like WM_INITMENU or WM_INITMENUPOPUP?

Comment: You can pre-calculate it before you create your window. You just need to know the font.

Comment: _"the standard menu doesn't work well in some mixed DPI situations"_ - You should add details about the original problem, ideally with a screenshot. You are asking about your supposed solution Y, but maybe the problem can be solved better when we now more about the X of your [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @zett42, I knew someone would come up with the XY problem :)
Actually, the problems with the standard menu in mixed DPI systems (f.i. main screen on 100%, app moved to monitor with 200% => menu is only half size) are only one trigger for this approach. There are some other reasons to do this. After all, why are owner drawn menus available in the first place? The request for having the same look might just be a basic requirement on which I am going to build on. Anyway, if I wanted a solution for making the standard menu work in mixed DPI systems, I would have asked for that.

Comment: Owner draw menus exist so you can add color and fancy items etc. It was also a common solution to get full color icons+text in a menu before WinVista (and the only way on Win95).

Answer (score 0):

This is [how ReactOS does it](https://github.com/reactos/reactos/blob/master/win32ss/user/ntuser/menu.c):

To measure a menu item:

```
if ((p = wcschr( lpitem->Xlpstr, '\t' )) != NULL) {
    RECT tmprc = rc;
    LONG tmpheight;
    int n = (int)( p - lpitem->Xlpstr);
    /* Item contains a tab (only meaningful in popup menus) */
    /* get text size before the tab */
    txtheight = DrawTextW( hdc, lpitem->Xlpstr, n, &rc,
        DT_SINGLELINE|DT_CALCRECT);
    txtwidth = rc.right - rc.left;
    p += 1; /* advance past the Tab */
    /* get text size after the tab */
    tmpheight = DrawTextW( hdc, p, -1, &tmprc,
                           DT_SINGLELINE|DT_CALCRECT);
    lpitem->dxTab += txtwidth;
    txtheight = max( txtheight, tmpheight);
    txtwidth += MenuCharSize.cx + /* space for the tab */
                tmprc.right - tmprc.left; /* space for the short cut */
}
```

Then to draw it:

```
Text = lpitem->Xlpstr;
if(Text)
{
    for (i = 0; Text[i]; i++)
        if (Text[i] == L'\t' || Text[i] == L'\b')
            break;
}

if(lpitem->fState & MF_GRAYED)

DrawTextW( hdc, Text, i, &rect, uFormat);

/* paint the shortcut text */
if (!menuBar && L'\0' != Text[i])  /* There's a tab or flush-right char */
{
    if (L'\t' == Text[i])
    {
        rect.left = lpitem->dxTab;
        uFormat = DT_LEFT | DT_VCENTER | DT_SINGLELINE;
    }
    else
    {
        rect.right = lpitem->dxTab;
        uFormat = DT_RIGHT | DT_VCENTER | DT_SINGLELINE;
    }

    DrawTextW( hdc, Text + i + 1, -1, &rect, uFormat );
}
```

So to insert a keyboard accelerator in a menu item, you simply separate it from the item text with the tab character. The measuring and drawing code then looks for this tab character and acts accordingly.

Note, however, that for the keyboard accelerator to be right-aligned in the menu like it is in your screenshot (which is achieved with `DrawText` with `DT_RIGHT`) the drawing code expects it to be separated from the item text with the `'\b'` character, not the tab character, and unless I'm missing something this is not accounted for in the measuring code, so you might want to compensate for that.

Comment: But does ReactOS support high DPI?

Comment: Not sure if that's relevant. Seems to me that the OP was unclear on exactly how the gap between the text and the accelerator was achieved so he can measure and draw himself precisely to work around some high DPI issues on Windows, not ReactOS. This should be enough to get him going if I understood the problem correctly.

Comment: Of course it is, in the code you posted `MenuCharSize.cx` is a magic number coming from somewhere and if it is not high DPI aware it is not going to look correct at higher DPI.

Answer (score 0):

Replicating the standard menu with owner draw is a world of pain. You have to deal with Visual Styles on and off, mnemonics/[Access keys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742464(v=vs.85).aspx#Access_keys), accessibility and all the undocumented metrics. It is better just to use the normal menu if you can.

Per-monitor DPI support seems to change in every Windows 10 release. 1607 added [`EnableNonClientDpiScaling`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt748621(v=vs.85).aspx) which scales the menu and other non-client areas. 1703 added Per Monitor v2 and MSDN says this about PMv2:

> - Scaling of non-client area - All windows will automatically have their non-client area drawn in a DPI sensitive fashion. Calls to EnableNonClientDpiScaling are unnecessary.
> - Scaling of Win32 menus - All NTUSER menus created in Per Monitor v2 contexts will be scaling in a per-monitor fashion.

Notepad is PMv2 and its menu seems to work fine:

[image: Per-monitor menu example]

Windows 8.1 and < 10 Anniversary Update will require more work and I would suggest that you just don't declare yourself DPI aware on these systems and let Windows scale your window for you (with some blurriness) if the system has multiple monitors.

Comment: I totally agree with the world of pain. Although I can reproduce the shown behavior for Notepad (even on Win10.1709), I am not able to achieve the same with my own application. A simple call to TrackPopupMenu with a hidden HWND receiving the messages opens only half the size on the second monitor with 200%. Any hints what I have to do to make it work? How does TrackPopupMenu determine the proper DPI?

Comment: I would assume it calls `GetDpiForWindow` but I have not checked. Why is your window hidden? Try making it 1x1 and visible on the monitor where the click happens, or even better, as a child of the window that was clicked because child windows inherit their parents DPI IIRC. Remember that different threads and windows in a process can have different DPI awareness on recent Windows versions.

Comment: First of all: Thanks for your participation! I will formulate a separate question for this as it is a bit off topic from the original question. I will post a link here when I have done that.